# FFmpeg.AutoGen for converting MP3 already in memory to Wav

Tags: ffmpeg

We are implementing a Web service, and the goal is to convert short (a few seconds) mp3 audios to WAV on the fly. The input mp3 content is a binary payload to the service. The speed of our web service is critical, so, saving and reading mp3 and wav from files (even with memory disk) are not an option.

It seems that all the functions provided in ffmpeg.autogen require either the filepath or url. Any suggestions that we could do the conversion for the mp3 content, which is already in memory?

BTW, we are aware of this post: [How to convert wav file to mp3 in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50614636/how-to-convert-wav-file-to-mp3-in-memory), which uses NAudio, but we would like to try ffmpeg, for comparing the speed and some other purposes. Many thanks indeed.